# How to store data and update it in user phone using Adobe AIR app for Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I'm a newbie programmer, so I'm sorry that this might be a very noob question.
I have a question about the project that I'm about to create. I've searched the google and don't know the proper keywords, so I didn't find any answer yet.

So, here it is: I'm going to create an Android app, developed using Adobe AIR. The app will show list of ads and stores in a mall. I want to update the ads (because this will change regularly) by connecting to the website, only when there is update (database changed) and when there is internet connection available. So if there is no internet connection available, the app won't update and will use the old data -> so the user can still use the app offline.

So in my opinion, there should be some files (images and text) that I need to store inside the .apk. These files will be used when the app goes offline, and replaced when the app is updating. Is that possible? and how do I do this? I hope you guys can give me some enlightened direction. :D

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather simple problem to solve. Basically, you check for an update every time the app launches (or the user requests it). You send the last updated time (always in UTC) to the server to check if there has been an update since then. If there has, send the new data. If there hasn't, send no new data or a status code saying no new data. Something like this:

```
var f:File;
var fs:FileStream;
var dataToUse:Object;

function init():void {
    f = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("server-data.txt");
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
    req.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
    req.data = new URLVariables();
    req.data['time'] = f.exists ? f.modificationDate.time : 0;
    req.url = "url goes here";
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
    loader.load(req);
}

function completeHandler(e:Event):void {
    // check if there was an update
    if (isUpdated) {
        saveNewData(e.target.data);
    }
    else {
        loadOldData();
    }
}

function ioErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
    loadOldData();
}

function saveNewData(data:String):void {
    // save the data to disk
    fs = new FileStream();
    fs.open(f, FileMode.WRITE);
    fs.writeUTFBytes(data);
    fs.close();

    //parse data here
    dataToUse = parsedData;
}

function loadOldData():void {
    if (f.exists) {
        fs = new FileStream();
        fs.open(f, FileMode.OPEN);
        var data:String = fs.readUTFBytes();
        fs.close();

        // parse data
        dataToUse = parsedData;
    }
    else {
        // display error
    }
}
```

This will require the server be able to understand what the timestamp you are sending them means, obviously. Otherwise, you could just call for new data each time and update each time, keeping the old data only for times when there is an error.

Quick note about my example above: I did take a few shortcuts and didn't show everything, such as data parsing and how to check if there was an update. These are things that will be specific to your server's data return, so I cannot realistically guess how to handle that.

Comment: Thanks @JoshJanusch, this is really helpful. I'm going to try your example soon. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the File and [FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) classes in AIR to allow saving locally to Android and iPhone/iPad. You can find more examples [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7dc2.html)

By default, an android application doesn't have permission to write to external storage. WIll be necessary
to set the **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission to my applications XML descriptor file ("YourAppName-app.xml").

```
<android>  
   <manifestAdditions>
      <![CDATA[  
         <manifest>  
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
         </manifest>  
      ]]>
   </manifestAdditions>  
 </android>
```

Comment: So you're aware, since you appear to be a newer member (based on rep), it is generally frowned upon to link out to non-documentation sources without providing the code from the source. SO is meant to be an archived Q&A site, and if that link you posted goes down, your answer would be completely useless in the future.

Comment: Hey @JoshJanusch, thank you for your constructive comment, I really appreciate. Just removed that tutorial URL and added an official Adobe URL with some examples. I'm sure that will help him to understand the API and all possibilities and also, improve himself to be able to define the best solution should be implemented.

Comment: Hey @gPeart, thanks for your answer. Is that possible to save the data inside the .apk? I don't want to save the data to the external storage (memory card) , since the user can access and accidentally remove them so that will cause the app to crash.

Comment: @ariespranata If you follow my answer and save to `File.applicationStorageDirectory` it will save the data to a sandboxed folder the user cannot access without rooting their phone. The actual APK (and IPA for that matter) are read-only after installation.